# opening PDF file in iframe on certain page

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, iframe

I have an iframe which uses a Url.Action to open a PDF from an action controller. Is it possible to open this PDF on a certain page? Determined by a value in the model e.g. @Model.FilePage

iframe:

```
        <iframe width="700" height="1600" src="@Url.Action("OpenPDF", new { id = 8 })"></iframe>
```

controller action:

```
public ActionResult OpenPDF(int? id)
        {
            CompletedCamp completedCamp = db.CompletedCamps.Find(id);
            string filepath = Server.MapPath(Path.Combine("~/Surveys/" + completedCamp.SurveyName));
            return File(filepath, "application/pdf");
        }
```

Comment: what the `File(filepath, "application/pdf");` returns ? If return a link the pdf then it work. If return data, will not work.

Comment: @Artistos it returns a PDF file

Comment: @Aristos any idea how I can pass a page number in please?

Comment: take a look at -> https://helpx.adobe.com/acrobat/kb/link-html-pdf-page-acrobat.html

Comment: Thanks @Aristos. Do you know if it is possible to add on to an Url.Action method? i.e. something like src="@Url.Action("OpenPDF", new { id = 8 }) +#page4"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To open on specific page, `add #page=[page number]` to the end of src

```
<iframe width="700" height="1600" src="@Url.Action("OpenPDF", new { id = 8 })#page=4"></iframe>
```

if page number should be from the model, do

```
public ActionResult Index()
{
    MyViewModel m = new MyViewModel() { FilePage = 4 }; 
    return View(m);
}

...
@model MVC.MyViewModel 

<iframe width="700" height="1600" src="@Url.Action("OpenPDF", new { id = 8 })#page=@Model.FilePage"></iframe>
```